# Redirected non-admin users. Now after deleting the code non-admins still can't login

Tags: wordpress, redirect, admin

I have used the following code to redirect non-admin users to the home page. Now after deleting the code, the effect is irreversible. non-admins still redirecting after login.

```
add_action( 'init', 'restrict_wp_dashboard_init' );
function restrict_wp_dashboard_init() {
    if ( is_admin() && ! current_user_can( 'administrator' ) &&
    !( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX ) ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url() );
        exit;
    }
}
```

Help !!!